# mvn: Permission denied

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04

when I run `mvn --version` in terminal this message appears

```
bash: /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn: Permission denied
```

I run this command

```
chmod a+x /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn
```

but not solved.

```
ls -l /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6185 Dec 24 16:25 /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn
```

tnx

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn

Comment: and with `-R`, puppies die too :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> bash: /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn: Permission denied
> ```

Typical reasons why this can happen:

- You don't have exec permission on the file `/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn`
- You don't have exec permission on one or more of the directories leading up to that file:

  - /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin
  - /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.5
  - /usr/local/apache-maven
  - ...
- The partition of `/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin` is mounted with the `noexec` flag on

If you check each of these and resolve, you should be able to execute.